# How does this function reverse a string recursively in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, recursion

I have read several posts on stack overflow and watched many youtube videos on this but I just don't understand how this code works. I understand that 'reverse(s.slice(1))' is recursively slicing until the string is just one letter, but where does the string get put back together in reverse order? also, what is the role of '+ s[0]' in this function?

```js
function reverse(s) {
    if (s.length===1) return s;
    return reverse(s.slice(1)) + s[0];
}
```

Comment: If `s = 'abcde'`, then `s.slice(1)` is ` `'bcde'`, so the function returns `reverse( 'bcde' ) + 'a'` which is  `'edcb' + 'a'`, which is `'edcba'`.

Comment: draw a stack on the paper and check with a pen, then you'll understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take, for example, the input `abcd`.

On the initial call, `return reverse(s.slice(1)) + s[0];` runs. Resolving the arguments, this turns into `return reverse('bcd') + 'a';` - it takes off the last letter of the string and calls itself recursively with the first characters.

With `reverse('bcd')`, this returns `reverse('cd') + 'b'`.

With `reverse('cd')`, this returns `reverse('d') + 'c'`.

`reverse('d')` returns `'d'`.

At this point, the recursive calls and returns get to resolve themselves. `reverse('d') + 'c'`. is `'d' + 'c'`, or `'dc'`.

`reverse('cd') + 'b'` is `'dc' + 'b'`, or `'dcb'`.

`reverse('bcd') + 'a';` is `'dcb' + 'a'`, or `'dcba'`, which is returned to the initial call of `reverse('abcd')`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive function. Recursion occurs when a thing is defined in terms of itself or of its type.

In this case, `function reverse(s)` is being called at the very end.

The `s.slice(1)` grabs all the value except the very first value and then add s[0].

This website will let you visualize your recursion easily.
https://visualgo.net/en/recursion

If you are still having trouble understanding, let  me know. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Each time the function calls itself, it passes one less character, until the length of the passed string is 1, which is the point when we start to propagate the return values

Check this illustration:

Input: "JOHN"

[image]